# Gulp copy of file working on OSX, not on Win7

Tags: macos, windows-7, gulp, relative-path

I am still fairly new to gulp and I am trying something which I do not think should be too difficult to do.

Basically I was given the string calculator kata to do at work - however I got tired of copying and cleaning files all the time, so I want to archive what I did and start with a fresh copy.

On my Mac (which I use at home), I created a solution to this using gulp, however, at work we have Windows 7 machines. On my Mac the solution works perfectly, but on the Win 7 machine at work it hangs as gulp gets to the first task.

Terminal readout on Mac:

```
[13:20:13] Using gulpfile ~/Code/Jasmine-Node-String-Kata/gulpfile.js
[13:20:13] Starting 'refresh'...
[13:20:13] Starting 'archive-implementation'...
[13:20:13] Finished 'archive-implementation' after 17 ms
[13:20:13] Starting 'archive-test'...
[13:20:13] Finished 'archive-test' after 2.48 ms
[13:20:13] Starting 'clean'...
[13:20:13] Finished 'clean' after 5.99 ms
[13:20:13] Starting 'refresh-test'...
[13:20:13] Finished 'refresh-test' after 1 ms
[13:20:13] Starting 'refresh-implementation'...
[13:20:13] Finished 'refresh-implementation' after 764 μs
[13:20:13] Finished 'refresh' after 31 ms
```

Console readout on Win 7 PC:

```
[13:23:07] Using gulpfile C:\Code\JS\Jasmine-Node-String-Calculator Kata\gulpfile.js
[13:23:07] Starting 'refresh'...
[13:23:07] Starting 'archive-implementation'...
```

At this point it the gulp taks hangs indefinitely.

I first thought this might be an issue between relative path differences between Windows and OSX, but nothing I did regarding this made the tasks complete successfully.

I also investigated whether it might be a rights issue on my Windows machine, but I have Admin rights and this should not be an issue.

At this point I am stumped and have no idea what is causing this issue.

My code is on a git repo and can be found here: [Jasmine-Node-String-Calculator-Kata](https://github.com/MrThursday/Jasmine-Node-String-Calculator-Kata)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that certain characters in Windows are illegal in folder names as compared to OSX. I was constructing a folder name which would contain the date and time like this:

```
date.join(".") + " " + time.join(":") + " " + suffix;
```

On OSX this is fine, however ":" is illegal in Windows file systems for folders. I have changed this now to:

```
date.join(".") + "_" + time.join(".") + " " + suffix;
```